# Querying a model by a has many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to query my model by an associated model.

Pseudo code:
@drinks = Drink.where(drink.ingredients ARE IN cabinet.ingredients)

Drink Model

```
class Drink < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :recipe_steps, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_steps
end
```

Ingredient Model

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :recipe_steps
  has_many :drinks, through: :recipe_steps
  has_many :cabinet_ingredients
  belongs_to :cabinet
end
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :cabinet
end
```

Edit: As suggested I tried

```
Drink.joins(ingredients: :cabinet_ingredients)
```

However it returns multiple records of the same drink when I have one drink with 2 ingredients from my cabinet and/or multiple users.

I need to return only one record of the drink.. In addition, I need to only return a drink if all of its ingredients are matched in the cabinet

Comment: In regards to the answer below: if you want to eliminate the duplicate records you could just call `.uniq` on your `@drinks` array.

Comment: Ok, but how do I narrow that down to the specific user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. Select a drink if all its ingredients are present in the given cabinet's ingredients.  I know its not using `Drink.where` like your pseudo code but it would get the job done.

```
Drink.all.select{|drink| drink.ingredients.all?{|drink_ingredient| cabinet.ingredients.include?(drink_ingredient)}}
```

Comment: Thats going to be really slow when you have a lot of drinks

Comment: This works. I went and built a sql statement that does this, I'm pretty sure it does the same thing  select distinct drink_id from recipe_steps where drink_id not in (select distinct drink_id from recipe_steps r left join cabinet_ingredients i on i.ingredient_id = r.ingredient_id where i.ingredient_id is null)

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
Drink.joins(ingrediants: :cabinet_ingredients).uniq
```

Comment: 2 problems with this. When I have multiple ingredients in my cabinet and I have drinks with multiple ingredients, it returns the same drink for both ingredient queries. Also if I have 2 users, it returns the drink twice, one for each user